# Use SQLCMD to execute script return Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, qsqlquery

I have to insert a very large amount of data in sql, the operation did not work via SQL Management Studio therefore I was investigating the insert via `sqlcmd`. so what I did was the following:

1. create a file.sql that contains the following query (multiple times):

   ```
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tblAccount] 
                  WHERE [AccountID] = 117242 AND
                        [TimeStamp] = CAST(N'2013-01-16 05:53:50.490' AS DateTime)) 
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO
           [dbo].[tblAccount] ([AccountID]
                              ,[Name]
                              ,[Comment]
                              ,[IsMachine]
                              ,[UserID]
                              ,[Prefix]
                              ,[Action]
                              ,[Initials]
                              ,[Name]
                              ,[TimeStamp]
                              ,[Reason]
                              ,[Iscal]) 
                       VALUES (117242
                              ,'blabla'
                              ,'The users project)'
                              ,1
                              ,'val'
                              ,39
                              ,'val'
                              ,'blabla'
                              ,'blabla'
                              ,CAST(N'2013-01-16 05:53:50.490' AS DateTime)
                              ,'NORMAL'
                              ,'0')
   END
   ```
2. I saved the file into a folder and then from the command line I do the following:

   ```
   C:\>sqlcmd -S pc_name\MSSQLEXPRESS -i"C:\Users\name\Desktop\OutPut\Result tblAccount.sql"
   ```

I get the following error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server pc_name\MSSQLEXPRESS, Line 1
>   
> Invalid object name 'dbo.tblAccount'.

I'm not sure if it is related to the syntax of the sql or in the way I write the sqlcmd.

Comment: Can you try aiming for exact server also like `[YourServerName].[dbo].[tblAccount]`

Comment: Maybe your default database is the wrong one. Try the `-d` swtich to `USE` a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's an over a year ago question, but in case somebody run into the same issue, make sure to provide credentials. I just ran into same issue and without providing credentials, sqlcmd issues that error. I don't know what's happening behind the scene, but seems that it connects to some sort of default db when authentication fails and couldn't find the table as a result.

```
 sqlcmd -S <computer name> -U <username> -P <password> -i  <absolute path to your script>
```